# Python boolean check in other functions

Tags: python

this is my code for a password and I actually have 4 conditions. Then, I am cheking at the end with def final_password that if all of the 4 previous fuctions are TRUE then the password in TRUE otherwise it's FALSE. However, the last one did not work, during my testing it was always FALSE even when the 4 conditions where TRUE. Thank you!

```
NON_ALPHABETIC_CARACTERS = ("!", "?", "§")

def password_len (password) :
    lenght_caracters_check = False

    for i in password :
        if len(password) > 4 and len(password) < 10 :
            lenght_caracters_check = True
            break
        else :
            return lenght_caracters_check 



def password_numeric_caracters (password) :
    numeric_caracters_check = False

    for i in password :
        if i.isnumeric () :
            numeric_caracters_check = True
            break
        else :
            return numeric_caracters_check



def password_alphabetic_caracters (password) :
    alphabetic_caracters_check = False

    for i in password :
        if i.isalpha () :
            alphabetic_caracters_check = True
            break
        else :
            return alphabetic_caracters_check 



def special_caracters (password) :
    special_caracters_check = False

    for i in password :
        if i in NON_ALPHABETIC_CARACTERS :
            special_caracters_check = True
            break
        else :
            return special_caracters_check 

def final_password (password) :
    final_password_check = False
    if password_len(password) and password_numeric_caracters(password) and password_alphabetic_caracters(password) and password_special_caracters(password)  :
        final_password_check  = True
    return final_password_check
```

Comment: In some of your functions, not all paths return a value. For example, in `password_len`, what is returned when `if len(password) > 4 and len(password) < 10 :` is true?

Comment: Also, all of your for loops exit after the first iteration, so they will never check beyond the first character.

Comment: At least `special_characters` returns false when there're no special characters yet you expect all true.

Comment: password_len(password) - you don't need a for loop there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add "return" to all functions for True cases.

For True cases you are just setting a variable true. However you are not returning it.

In addition there is no overall check for all characters since you are breaking the loop for the first success case. You need to modify break with continue:

```
   for i in password :
        if i.isalpha () :
              continue
        else :
              return False
   return True
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some other issues with your code, but answering your question, your function special_caracters(password) does not return any value when the condition is True. Try refactoring it a bit:

```
def special_caracters (password):

    for i in password:
        if i in NON_ALPHABETIC_CARACTERS:
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: Thank you! fabio.avigo, what are the other issues? thanks

Comment: Thanks, I still don't know what to do for the final password check, to check if every other fuctions are TRUE